# cap staging deploy - SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: rake exit status: 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I execute `cap staging deploy`, the error occured:

```
00:09 deploy:migrate
      [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
** Invoke deploy:migrating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Execute deploy:migrating
00:09 deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
      01
      01   * development - set it to false
      01   * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
      01   * production - set it to true
      01
      01 rake aborted!
      01 ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'staging' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"]
      01 /var/www/demo-unicorn/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.…
```

My `database.yml`:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

My `Capfile`:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include capistrano-rails
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Include capistrano-rails
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
require 'capistrano/upload-config'
require 'capistrano/ssh_doctor'

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
# require "capistrano/bundler"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

My `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.9'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.3'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'capistrano3-nginx'
  gem 'capistrano-upload-config'
  gem 'capistrano-ssh-doctor', '~> 1.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My `config/deploy.rb`:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.10.1"

set :application, "demo-unicorn"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:liamyabou/demo-unicorn.git"
set :branch, 'master'
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

My `config/deploy/staging.rb`:

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

# server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
# server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server "db.example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{db}
server '88.99.187.171', user: 'root', roles: %w{app web db}


# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}
role :app, %w{root@88.99.187.171}
role :web, %w{root@88.99.187.171}
role :db,  %w{root@88.99.187.171}


# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.



# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
server '88.99.187.171', user: 'root', roles: %w{app web db}


# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}
role :app, %w{root@88.99.187.171}
role :web, %w{root@88.99.187.171}
role :db,  %w{root@88.99.187.171}
```

I spent hours and hours, please give me some ideas~

Comment: Please show us your config/database.yml file

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear - your database.yml file defines the database names that you have, and there is no database named "staging" configured there.  What database are you expecting your staging environment to use, and what are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `mysql` instead of the default `sqlite`, the error is eliminated;

The file path `config\database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: your_password
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: unicorn_development


staging:
  <<: *default
  database: unicorn_staging
  pool: 5


production:
  <<: *default
  database: unicorn_production
  pool: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have staging database in database.yml

   staging:
     <<: *default

   database: db/staging.sqlite3
2. If you still have a problem. Ensure that you created a staging database.

Answer (score 0):

A proper database.yml looks like this on staging or production

```
development: &default
  adapter: adapter name (sqlite , postgresql or mysql)
  encoding: utf8
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] %>

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

The values are to be stored in an .env file which is usually hidden . But in your case , you are directly asking it to migrate without creating . A workaround to this is to directly creating database with name "staging" in whichever database you are using , the migrations will work after that . I would strongly suggest against creating manually , as it might caught issues if you are to move this app in another environment .